# Can't connect to wifi after software update on ubuntu 12.10. Additional drivers says it is working. BCM4312

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I'm new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu last night as a dual boot with Windows 7. When I first installed it using USB the WiFi worked. Then I figured out how to use the Software Updater and updated it, downloading about 200 MB of updates.

Then the WiFi stopped working. For the record, I've seen numerous threads about this same topic and have tried basically everything they have said to try. Finally a little while ago my wifi indicator/switch on my laptop is on after one of the codes I put in  terminal, but still no wifi connection showing up.

Additional Drivers says the driver is working though. One odd thing was, when I tried installing the kernels and such in terminal that other people were saying worked, it kept saying cannot find installer or whatever on `E:/` to install it, but that's my CD-ROM drive and I used USB to install. So i'm wondering if its looking in the wrong place for the firmware?

My laptop is a hp pavilion and this is my result of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a43] (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2942] (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2944] (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 [8086:2946] (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:294a] (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2939] (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller [8086:2919] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2929] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem [8086:2932] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use the same syntax as Windows for drives. Drive letters are not used in Ubuntu (though you'll use them if you install a Wubi system in Windows...which does not seem to be what you did). However, often when installing/updating software on Ubuntu fails, you are informed of the errors that occurred, and those lines start with `E:` (which stands for error). It seems highly likely that's what you're seeing (which means it has nothing to do with where *on your computer* it is looking for anything). Though you've provided some valuable information, this is unanswerable without more.

Comment: You said "*For the record, I've seen numerous threads about this same topic and have tried basically everything they have said to try*".  If we're going to do any better for you than those threads, you'll need to link to all (or as many as possible) of them (you can leave the leading `http://` off links to let you post them, then we can edit them back to working order after checking them, this is a new user restriction), and you'll need to tell us all the things you tried and what happened, in as much detail as possible.

Comment: What exactly are the `E:` errors you see? When you "*tried installing the kernels and such*" exactly what were you trying to install, exactly what commands did you run, and what was the *complete and exact* text from the the terminal? You can do it again, then copy all text from the terminal to the clipboard, paste it into your question or at http://paste.ubuntu.com (if you do that, you can add the link in your question or, if you can't add anymore links, you can post it in a comment). What's the output of `ifconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network`? (Please add all this info to your question.)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding so quickly. I actually just ended up fixing it by using the additional driver update via terminal with the code jockey-kde which manually launched the updater and im guessing intalled the update again (fixing it). Next it asked me to activate the driver saying it was inactive so i did that and it told me to restart and when i did the wifi networks came up and was able to log in and use the wifi so i guess an admin can mark this as solved. Oh and this is the youtube link to the code i used in terminal. Go to 0:50 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6M2GjvI8EQ

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using `jockey-kde` to manually start additional driver updater which reinstalled the wifi driver, then activated it when the additional drivers window came up, restarted and wifi works again! Thanks for the responses Eliah!

Comment: You should select this as the answer of the question, since it was how you solved your issue.